# Perl: while with no conditional

Tags: perl, while-loop

According to the [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements), the `while` statement executes the block as long as the expression is [true](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood). I wonder why it becomes an infinite loop with an empty expression:

```
while () { # infinite loop
 ...
}
```

Is it just inaccuracy in the doc?

Comment: I prefer `while (1)` to emphasize the intent.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'while () { }'
while (1) {
    ();
}
-e syntax OK
```

It seems that `while () {}` and `while (1) {}` are equivalent. Also note that empty parens* are inserted in the empty block.

Another example of pre-defined compiler behaviour:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'while (<>) { }'
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    ();
}
-e syntax OK
```

I would say that this is just the docs not reporting a special case.

* — To be precise, the `stub` opcode is inserted. It does nothing, but serves a goto target for the `enterloop` opcode. There's no real reason to note this. Deparse denotes this `stub` op using empty parens, since parens don't generate code.

Comment: Curiously, `for(;;)` deparses as `while(1)` too.

Comment: @briandfoy Yes, I noticed that after posting this.. another special case. Even more curiously `for ()` is a syntax error, but `for (())` compiles, but does not compile into the `while(1)` case, but `foreach $_ (())`.

Comment: @TLP No, that last one makes sense. `for ()` has two syntaxes I know of: C-style and foreach over list.  So it doesn't know which one you want.  `for (())` is a foreach over an empty array:  `perl -e 'for (()) { print "foo" ;}'`

Comment: @Izkata Empty *list*, an empty array would be `[]`. `for` is simply an alias for `foreach`, they are interchangeable. The curious part is that `while()` and `for(;;)` are considered infinite loops, `for(())` is not, even though its loop condition is also empty. `for(())` is a redundant statement, as it will never execute.

Comment: @TLP Welll... Empty something.  Still a Perl beginner here, so I get `[]` and `()` confused on occasion.  But my general point still stands - `for (())` isn't an empty condition like `while ()`, although I agree it seems a bit odd that it's not just removed.

Comment: Sorry, but your post is wrong. The `1` is added by Deparse, not the by compiler. `while (1) { }` and `while () { }` both compile to the same code, so Deparse has to Deparse them the same, and it chose to deparse to the less confusing `while (1) { }`. If you look at the actual code produced (`-MO=Concise`), you'll see there is no `1` added. There is no condition at all, in fact. The `1` gets *removed* for `while (1) { }`.

Comment: @brian d foy, All of `for (;;) { ... }`, `while () { ... }` and `while (TRUE) { ... }` compile to a condition-less loop (`loop { ... }`). Deparse has no way of knowing what the original code was.

Comment: @TLP, I found a way of fixing the post without significantly altering it. Done.

Answer (score 14):

This is a special case of the concept of [Vacuous Truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth#Scope_of_the_concept). If there is no condition, the statement *while the condition is true* is itself vacuously true.

If I am reading this correctly, the relevant piece of code seems to be [around line 5853 of `op.c`](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/906024c7fead4086ed911b8052d784aa07c2f1e2:/op.c#l5853) in 5.14.1:

```c
5853     if (expr) {
5854         scalar(listop);
5855         o = new_logop(OP_AND, 0, &expr, &listop);
5856         if (o == expr && o->op_type == OP_CONST && !SvTRUE(cSVOPo->op_sv)) {
5857             op_free(expr);              /* oops, it's a while (0) */
5858             op_free((OP*)loop);
5859             return NULL;                /* listop already freed by new_logop */
5860         }
5861         if (listop)
5862             ((LISTOP*)listop)->op_last->op_next =
5863                 (o == listop ? redo : LINKLIST(o));
5864     }
5865     else
5866         o = listop;
```

I am assuming with no `expr` in the condition, we reach `o = listop`. `listop` was previously defined as `listop = op_append_list(OP_LINESEQ, block, cont);`.

Comment: I don't think that's it; that o=listop may be the non-looping `while(())` case.  `while()` is actually implemented in the parser (perly.y); see the texpr rule, which is either nothing (in which case it literally pretends it saw a '1') or an expr.

Answer (score 12):

This is a special case.  An empty condition expression defaults to just `true`, which means "loop forever, or until a `break`.  In C (and perl) the idiom

```
for(;;) {
   // Neverending fun
}
```

has the same effect for the same reason.

There doesn't appear to be any mention of this in the official perl docs, and yet there is a special rule in the parser for it.  Perhaps it's because nobody uses it :)

The `for(;;)` idiom is less uncommon though.

Comment: If it is, it certainly needs a mention in the doc.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Sure.  There are some specific things defined as false (0, "", undef).  Everything else is by default true.

Comment: it's not a default.  I just checked the parser code.  There is a special parsing rule for it.

Comment: That makes sense, since if () and until () are syntax errors.

Comment: It's now documented in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops that `for (;;) { ... }` and `while () { ... }` are infinite loops.